# Does the critical value show how far we can deviate from the sample mean?

Tags: inference

I understand that the margin of error is the z score (1.96 for a 95% confidence interval) multiplied by the standard error.

Is it correct to say that when you add two standard errors to both sides of the sample mean, you will capture the actual mean 95% of the time? So from this, is it correct to say that the critical value will determine how far the standard error will deviate from the center, and thus determines the level of confidence?

Basically, I still do not fully understand why we need to multiply by a z-value, which I guess is from a separate normal distribution?

Comment: I think you are trying to ask an important question, and the answer will help you grasp some fundamental concepts in statistics. But neither your title nor your question is clear enough to answer. Please try to refine exactly what you are asking. Including an example may help.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it correct to say that when you add two standard errors to both sides of the sample mean, you will capture the actual mean 95% of the time?

That's essentially the frequentist interpretation (given repeated sampling), though the Bayesians take a different approach.

> [I]s it correct to say that the critical value will determine how far the standard error will deviate from the center, and thus determines the level of confidence?

I think you're conflating a few ideas here. A critical value like 1.96 is a function of how risk averse (or accepting) we are as researchers. It's not a function of the data. If I'm feeling very risk averse, I select a high critical threshold, but if I'm more risk-acceptant I choose a lower critical threshold.

The standard error is a function of the data and sample size ($\hat{\sigma}=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma}{n}}$, where $\sigma$ is a standard deviation, and $n$ is the size of a given sample). Therefore, a critical value cannot affect the value of a standard error.

Nevertheless, both a critical value and a standard error can affect confidence in a statistic. As (a) critical values get bigger and (b) standard errors get smaller, we become not only more confident about the interval in which a parameter exists but also we can be more precise in expressing the range of that interval.

> Basically, I still do not fully understand why we need to multiply by a z-value, which I guess is from a separate normal distribution?

A $z$-value simply measures the number of standard errors a point estimate falls from its null hypothesis using the sampling distribution. The sampling distribution is a standard normal distribution and is not the same thing as a distribution of observations from a single sample. The sampling distribution is the density distribution of sample means taken from many, many samples taken from the population of interest. We use the sampling distribution to hypothesis-test.

When you construct a confidence interval, you're multiplying not by a $z$-value but by a critical value like 1.96 (for 95 percent confidence using a two-tail test). Therefore, multiplying a standard error by a critical value, then adding and deducting that value from the point estimate, is what gives us our confidence interval.

Remember that $z$-values are measured in units of standard errors of the sampling distribution. They correspond to $p$-values, which tell us the proportion of the sampling distribution that either occurs up to or after that value of $z$. We use critical values like 1.96 because $z=1.96$ has a $p$-value of 0.025 in its left-tail and 0.025 in its right tail, meaning that: $\bar{x} \pm 1.96\times \hat{\sigma}$ describes the central 95 percent of the sampling distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I found online that a null hypothesis is "the hypothesis that there is no significant difference between specified populations, any observed difference being due to sampling or experimental error.". What is meant by "a z value measures the number of SE a point falls from its null hypothesis"?

Comment: You hypothesize that degree earners make more than non-degree earners. A sample finds that degree-earners make $\$65,000$ and that non-degree earners make $\$45,000$. The null is that both types make the same amount of money. Suppose that the standard error is $\$10,000$. Then z=(65k-45k)/(10k)=2.00. You're 2 standard errors from the null. Under the z-dist., the probability that you observe degree earners making \$65k given they actually earn \$45k is 0.023. Put differently, there's a 23 in 1000 chance we observe a value of \$65k given that the real value is $45k as a matter of chance.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that the critical value multiplied by the standard error measures the number of standard errors the confidence interval is made of?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Why do we go (65k-45k)/(10k)?

Comment: The formula for a z-score is: $z=\frac{H_a-H_0}{\hat{\sigma}}$, where $H_a$ is the hypothesized parameter, $H_0$ is the null, and $\hat{\sigma}$ is the standard error. So we're just using the equation for a $z$-score. The $z$-score itself measures the number of standard errors we are from the null, so hesitate to adopt your definition of what standard error times the critical value is. The critical value multiplied by the standard error, added and subtracted from the point estimate, is merely the confidence interval.

Comment: Right, that last sentence really clears things up. I haven't got to p-scores and nulls yet (sorry should have said that earlier), so could you just really basically say what is meant by "number of standard errors from the null"? Thanks a lot

Comment: Rely on the formula for a $z$-score: $z=\frac{H_a-H_0}{\hat{\sigma}}$. In the numerator, we have the distance between the null and the alternative hypothesis. That's the distance from the null. And in the denominator, we have the standard error. Therefore, a $z$-score is by definition the number of standard errors an alternative hypothesis is from the null hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks, you said that "a z-value measures the number of standard errors a point estimate falls from its null hypothesis using the sampling distribution." But isn't it the number of standard deviations between the null and alternate hypothesis?

Comment: Also, I see a lot of resources online stating that the numerator is x bar minus the population mean, is that the same as Ha - H0? Is the null considered to be the population mean and the alternate a sample? (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8QR7wxmmQg&t=173s)

Comment: @David this is not a sound formula for a Z-score. a) $H_a$ and $H_0$ are symbolic representation of the alternative and null hypothesis. b) $H_0$ is the null hypothesis, so the corresponding "hypothesized estimate" is represented by subscript $_0$ and not $_a$ as you say. c) $\hat{\sigma}$ is an estimate of the standard *deviation*. The *standard error of the mean* is $\hat{\sigma}/\sqrt{n-1}$ and only when the distribution is normal.

Answer (score 1):

The critical value is a property of a distribution of a test statistic, specifically the test statistic under the null hypothesis. The sample mean does not depend on the null hypothesis. It *can* deviate quite far from the critical value, this is hopefully more likely to be the case when the null hypothesis is false.

When the sampling distribution of the test statistic follows a standard normal distribution under the null, it's quite easy to obtain some known probability bounds by looking at a number of standard deviations from the mean. But the sampling distribution of that test statistic under the null can follow any number of arbitrary distributions, so the critical value is a more general way of finding probability bounds.

When the sampling distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis follows a standard normal distribution, then a simple probability rule is that the $\pm$ 1.96 provides bounds that will contain the test statistic obtained under independent replications 95% of the time. This would b consistent with what we expect when the null is true. If the null is false, it will hopefully be different than that.

Comment: I'm having trouble following the final sentence of the second paragraph there. Are you envisioning a case where some of the assumptions don't hold, or are discussing something else?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica well suppose you are creating a test for the variance of a normally distributed random variable. The test statistic $\hat{\sigma}^2/\sigma_0^2$ follows a $\chi^2_1$ distribution under the null hypothesis, not a normal distribution, so the critical values will be asymmetric and not based on a number of standard errors from the null as with, say, the $Z$-test.

Comment: Ah. I was reading it as if the condition given in the first sentence of the paragraph applied to the whole paragraph, which made it sound contradictory. I should have realized to see it as drawing a contrast between two situations. Perfectly clear now. Thank you.