# z score relation to null hypothesis

Tags: inference

I am learning about z-scores, and I am trying to figure out what it is and why it is multiplied by the standard error to find the margin of error (which is used for the confidence interval).

I was recently watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8QR7wxmmQg&t=173s) about z-scores. It states that the z score is calculated by dividing (sample mean minus population mean) by the standard error.

However, in [another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/455793/does-the-critical-value-show-how-far-we-can-deviate-from-the-sample-mean/455804?noredirect=1#comment846347_455804) I asked, the person who answered stated that z scores are the number of standard errors an alternative hypothesis is from the null hypothesis and is calculated by  z = (Ha−H0) / σ^. Clearly, this means that z -score shows the number of standard errors an alternative hypothesis is from the null hypothesis

Are both of these definitions the same, or are they different?  Can you say that the alternate hypothesis is the sample mean, while the null hypothesis is the actual population mean?

Comment: Although the answer you reference is a little vague, it does not assert anything like what you claim.  The Z-score is a property of the *data,* not of the hypotheses being made about them.  (A comparable property of the hypotheses--which of course is only a supposition, since we don't know which hypothesis, if any, holds!--is called an *effect size.*)

Comment: Thanks, he states that "a z-score is by definition the number of standard errors an alternative hypothesis is from the null hypothesis", am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: That quotation is from a comment.  I warmly recommend you disregard it, because IMHO if any statement like that ever appeared in an answer, that answer would receive many downvotes for being incorrect and deceptive.  (It's not possible to downvote comments, which is one reason among many they should always be read judiciously.)